# Emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU1 main loop'. No response for 105001 ms

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use Gitlab CI for continuous integration. After every commit I have 3 jobs in the pipeline: debug, unitTests and instrumentedTests. But now instrumented tests failed because of the timeout. I added my gitlab-ci.yml file below

I've already tried downgrade android sdk versions, but no luck at all. Maybe there are some commands for yml-file that could fix the problem.

Also maybe somebody knows how to make all tests not failed for EMULATOR_VERSION > 22. 24 or higher never worked at all.

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "4333796" # from https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools
  EMULATOR_VERSION: "22"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail


stages:
  - build
  - test

assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test

instrumentedTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
    - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
    - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
    - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "emulator" "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};default;armeabi-v7a"  > installEmulator.log
    - echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-${EMULATOR_VERSION};default;armeabi-v7a"
    - android-sdk-linux/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
    - ./android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - ./gradlew connectedCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

There are following factors:

- looks like google dropped support of qemu engine and only ranchu is supported for now
- sdk was partially updated but there are bugs in update process

While qemu is no more supported this concrete bug with hanging seems wouldn't fixed ever.

For switch to ranchu environment:

- avoid using `*default*` platform for avd's, prefer `*google-api*`'s one (while ranchu kernel is missed in default platforms)
- update sdk with --channel=4

Just in case it helped me.